# How to use common variable names in sub Makefiles when I'm building multiple targets? (Makefile)

Tags: c, makefile, compiler-errors

Another day I end up struggling with Makefiles..
There were times I thought I understand basics of Makefile but I encounter this kind of situation all the time..
I have many test-benches and they share a common top Makefile and each has its own Makefile.inc file. I found the test-benches were not running correct because of the problem I'm describing below.  I made a simple example for this question.
This is the output of `tree` command.

```
.
|-- build
|   |-- test1
|   |   L-- Makefile.inc
|   L-- test2
|       L-- Makefile.inc
|-- common
|   L-- main.c
|-- Makefile
|-- test1
|   L-- testsrc
|       L-- test.c
|       L-- test.h
L-- test2
    L-- testsrc
        L-- test.c
        L-- test.h
```

And this is the sources and Makefiles.

#### ./Makefile

```
test_list = test1 test2
sub_makefiles = $(foreach test, $(test_list), build/$(test)/Makefile.inc)
include $(sub_makefiles)

all: build/test1/test build/test2/test

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    @rm -f $(foreach test, $(test_list), build/$(test)/*.o)
```

#### ./common/main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "test.h"
extern void print_test();

int main(void)
{
print_test();
printf("X = %d\n", X);
return 0;
}
```

#### ./test1/testsrc/test.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_test()
{
printf("this is test1\n");
}
```

#### ./test1/testsrc/test.h

```
#define X 1
```

#### ./test2/testsrc/test.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_test()
{
printf("this is test2\n");
}
```

#### ./test2/testsrc/test.h

```
#define X 2
```

#### ./build/test1/Makefile.inc

```
appname     := test1
dstdir        := build/$(appname)
common_srcdir := common
perapp_srcdir := $(appname)/testsrc

target = $(build)/$(appname)/$(appname)
$(dstdir)/main.o: common/main.c
    $(info appname = $(appname), perapp_srcdir = $(perapp_srcdir))
    echo " [CC  ] $<"
    $(CC) -I$(perapp_srcdir) $< -o $@

$(dstdir)/%.o : $(appname)/testsrc/%.c
    $(CC) $< -o $@

$(target): $(dstdir)/test.o $(dstdir)/main.o $(dstdir)/print_test.o
    echo " [LINK] $<"
    $(CC) $^ -o $@
```

#### ./build/test2/Makefile.inc

```
appname     := test2
dstdir        := build/$(appname)
common_srcdir := common
perapp_srcdir := $(appname)/testsrc

target = $(build)/$(appname)/$(appname)
$(dstdir)/main.o: common/main.c
    $(info appname = $(appname), perapp_srcdir = $(perapp_srcdir))
    echo " [CC  ] $<"
    $(CC) -I$(perapp_srcdir) $< -o $@

$(dstdir)/%.o : $(appname)/testsrc/%.c
    $(CC) $< -o $@

$(target): $(dstdir)/test.o $(dstdir)/main.o $(dstdir)/print_test.o
    echo " [LINK] $<"
    $(CC) $^ -o $@
```

This is the output when I ran `make`.

```
appname = test2, perapp_srcdir = test2/testsrc
echo " [CC  ] common/main.c"
 [CC  ] common/main.c
cc -Itest2/testsrc common/main.c -o build/test1/main.o
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc43yRNT.o: in function `main':
main.c:(.text+0xe): undefined reference to `print_test'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [build/test1/Makefile.inc:10: build/test1/main.o] Error 1
```

It is trying to make build/test1/main.o for the first target, but `appname` is set to `test2`. This is because I included two Makefile.inc files together at the top Makefile and the last assigned value is being used for both targets.   How should I handle this case? And why do I get `undefined reference to` print_test'` error when I declared extern and it will be linked later?

Comment: The first thing that jumps into my eyes: you assign to `target` with `=` which is a deferred assignment operator.

Comment: The second thing: you are using a kind of *recursive make* methodology but with only the drawbacks and not the benefits. I think that the way you are trying to parameterize your rules will result always in confusion as there is that global namespace for symbols which `make` inevitably uses and which is the reason why people still separate their builds into orthogonal subsets. You are deliberately subjecting your build to this global namespace while trying to keep a textual-only separation of your builds. IMHO it is time to reassess your build process.

Comment: Sorry for not being more of a help towards a solution to your current problem but I think in the long run you will be happier with another approach.

Comment: This is not a make issue. Your compilation commands should use the `-c` option (`$(CC) -I$(perapp_srcdir) -c $< -o $@`). Note that the `build` make variable you use is undefined.

Comment: Instead of including makefiles in other makefiles, you can execute the `make` command recursively. In your main makefile, subprojects can be targets, and the command(s) to build a subproject can include a `make` command. Then this `make` command would execute with its own variables. `make` has a variety of features to support this, including defining `MAKE` to be the path to the `make` executable being used, so you can use `$(MAKE)` for the command, a way to pass to the new `make` the same switches passed to the starting `make`, ways to pass “global” variables but not local ones, and so on.

Comment: start using https://github.com/cppfw/prorab it will solve all your problems

Comment: Using `:=` vs `=` assignment makes no difference here.  That only determines whether the expansion happens at assignment or not.  The problem is that the variable is reset multiple times before the recipes are run.

Comment: Hello all, thanks for the comments. I changed it to a recursive style, I think it's almost done but there is a problem.  new question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68441748/list-of-targets-used-as-target-of-a-rule-but-only-the-first-one-is-made-make . Please give me a comment or answer if you can spare some time. Thanks!

Comment: @MadScientist As I see it, the use of a deferred variable in the place of the rule-immediate in  `immediate : immediate ; deferred \n deferred` (https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Reading-Makefiles) forces make to expand it immediately. This may surprise a new user as the linked documentation is often overlooked although it is extremely significant, although not for this case. - Oh, saw your answer just now - nevermind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To understand why this is happening you need to really understand [how make reads makefiles](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Reading-Makefiles.html).

Looking at that page you can see that make variables *in recipes* are **always** expanded only when make is going to run the recipe, which happens after all makefiles have been parsed.

Since make variables are global, if you use the same variable name in different makefiles then you expand the value in a recipe, it will **always** have the value of the last assignment in any makefile.

You need to add scope to your makefile variables.  There are various ways to do this.  You might be interested in reading this set of blog posts: http://make.mad-scientist.net/category/metaprogramming/  Start with the one at the bottom and work your way up.

Comment: Thanks, it seem like a little advanced topic, I'll read it later when I find some time.