# list of targets used as target of a rule, but only the first one is made.. (Makefile)

Tags: c, makefile

This is a follow up question for [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68438544/how-to-use-common-variable-names-in-sub-makefiles-when-im-building-multiple-tar). I changed it to recursive make style.
This is the `tree` command output.

```
.
|-- build
|   |-- test1
|   |   L-- Makefile.inc
|   L-- test2
|       L-- Makefile.inc
|-- common
|   L-- main.c
|-- Makefile
|-- test1
|   L-- testsrc
|       L-- test.c
|       L-- test.h
L-- test2
    L-- testsrc
        L-- test.c
        L-- test.h
```

This is the file contents.

#### ./Makefile

```
test_list := test1 test2

.PHONY : $(test_list)
$(test_list) :
    make -C build/$@ -f Makefile.inc

# I want to merge the clean target but don't know how..
.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f build/*/*.o
    rm -f build/test1/test1
    rm -f build/test2/test2
```

#### ./common/main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "test.h"
extern void print_test();

int main(void)
{
print_test();
printf("X = %d\n", X);
return 0;
}
```

#### ./test1/testsrc/test.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_test()
{
printf("this is test1\n");
}
```

#### ./test1/testsrc/test.h

```
#define X 1
```

#### ./test2/testsrc/test.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_test()
{
printf("this is test2\n");
}
```

#### ./test2/testsrc/test.h

```
#define X 2
```

#### ./build/test1/Makefile.inc

```
appname     := test1
perapp_srcdir := $(appname)/testsrc
target = $(appname)

$(target): test.o main.o
    echo " [LINK] $<"
    $(CC) $^ -o $@

main.o: ../../common/main.c
    echo " [CC  ] $<"
    $(CC) -c -I../../$(appname)/testsrc $< -o $@

%.o : ../../$(appname)/testsrc/%.c
    $(CC) -c $< -o $@
clean :
    rm -f $(appname) *.o
```

#### ./build/test2/Makefile.inc

```
appname     := test2
perapp_srcdir := $(appname)/testsrc
target = $(appname)

$(target): test.o main.o
    echo " [LINK] $<"
    $(CC) $^ -o $@

main.o: ../../common/main.c
    echo " [CC  ] $<"
    $(CC) -c -I../../$(appname)/testsrc $< -o $@

%.o : ../../$(appname)/testsrc/%.c
    $(CC) -c $< -o $@
clean :
    rm -f $(appname) *.o
```

But when I do `make`,  only the first target(test1) is made.
This is the make output.

```
$make
make -C build/test1 -f Makefile.inc
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/ckim/testdir/testmake/testcvtestperappsrc/build/test1'
cc -c ../../test1/testsrc/test.c -o test.o
echo " [CC  ] ../../common/main.c"
 [CC  ] ../../common/main.c
cc -c -I../../test1/testsrc ../../common/main.c -o main.o
echo " [LINK] test.o"
 [LINK] test.o
cc test.o main.o -o test1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/ckim/testdir/testmake/testcvtestperappsrc/build/test1'
```

Why isn't the rule for test2 kicked in? (When I change the order to `test2 test1`, only test2 is made.

**ADD (Answer) :**

```
According to Renaud Pacalet's answer, the revised top Makefile is like this.  
test_list := test1 test2


.PHONY : all $(test_list)
all : $(test_list)
$(test_list):
    make -C build/$@ -f Makefile.inc

del_list := $(foreach t, $(test_list), build/$(t)/$(t))
.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f build/*/*.o
    rm -f $(del_list)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default make tries to build the first explicit target it finds (`test1` in your case). Add a phony target that depends on all the others, and make it the default by putting it first:

```
test_list := test1 test2

.PHONY: all $(test_list)

all: $(test_list)
```

Typing `make` or `make all` is now the same and `make all` builds all targets listed in the `test_list` variable.

Comment: Ah, that was it! Thank you so much!